Are \$v_{C}\$ and \$v_{L}\$ in phase in an LC oscillator?

Looking at these figures, I can't help but to conclude that \$v_{C}\$ and \$v_{L}\$ are in phase! Why? Well, because \$v_{C}=q/c\$ I know this is wrong but why?
Reference:
https://shorturl.at/30NEu


Are \$v_C\$ and \$v_L\$ in phase

The capacitor and inductor are connected in parallel: -

Therefore, \$v_C\$ and \$v_L\$ are in phase and equal.
On the other hand, if current is flowing out of the capacitor and into the inductor, although the current is the same, there is an inversion. As we know, if something flows out we might call it positive but, if it flows in to another component then, we are totally obliged to call that identical current negative.
Hence, the impedance of a capacitor is the mathematical negative of the impedance of an inductor that has the same reactance. We also call this resonance.

It makes sense. However, how can two pieces be in parallel when the same current follows in both of them? Isn't that how we define a series connection?

The current flows out from the capacitor and into the inductor hence, the currents are opposite and not equal except in magnitude.

By KVL, Vc = VL or Vc = -VL depends on how you define Vc and VL. They are surely in phase in these answers.
